# ERROR at line 2: PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER log_FAMILY_increase
  AFTER UPDATE OF FAMILY_INCOME ON STUDENT
  FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
   INSERT INTO STUDENT_2 (NAME, SURNAME, NEW_FAMILY_INCOME)
   VALUES (:NEW.NAME,SURNAME, :NEW.FAMILY_INCOME, 'New INCOME');
 END;
```

in oracle 10g i get this error message:
   ERROR at line 2: PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: still not working also i got for this code same error as well!!
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER plza
 BEFORE
  INSERT OR UPDATE OF FAMILY_INCOME, BIRTHDATE OR DELETE 
 ON STUDENT
BEGIN
 CASE
  WHEN INSERTING THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Inserting');
  WHEN UPDATING(FAMILY_INCOME) THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Updating FAMILY_INCOME');
  WHEN UPDATING(BIRTHDATE) THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('UPDATING BIRTHDATE');
  WHEN DELETING THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DELETING');
 END CASE;
END;

Comment: See my response below, I updated my statement..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a column name here "`(name, surname, new_family_income)`", as you are trying to insert 4 values into 3 columns.. I switched the statement, to not list out the columns, maybe that will help..

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER log_family_increase
   AFTER UPDATE OF family_income
   ON student
   REFERENCING NEW AS new OLD AS old
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO student_2 
        VALUES (:new.name,
                :new.surname,
                :new.family_income,
                'New INCOME');
END;
```

Comment: IT WORKS 
SO MANY THANX
I should be aware of the fourth column 
cuz it's edited from another example !!

Comment: @user3689309 - although leaving out the field list fixed this problem, I strongly recommend including the field list in each and every `INSERT` statement you write. First, it will protect the code when new columns are added to your table - you won't have to go back and fix up each and every `INSERT` statement for that table. Second, if this came across my desk for a code review, it'd be coming back dripping blood...errr, red ink. :-) Share and enjoy.